# tar extract a specific directory in a specific directory

Tags: command-line, tar

How can I extract a specific directory in a local directory ?
For instance,

```
$ mkdir project
$ ll
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 343535  8월 17 08:56 foo.tar.gz*
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root      0  8월 17 09:04 project/
```

`foo.tar.gz`'s root is a directory containing all the files I want to extract in `project`

I tried

`tar -C project -xzvf foo.tar.gz root_dir/`

no luck...

```
$ ls project
root_dir
```

Again, I need `root_dir`'s content in this example to be in `project` directory.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

my bad, the answer was just under my nose..

```
tar -C project/ --strip-components=1 -xzvf foo.tar.gz root_dir
```